# Does anyone know of an open source application that stores libraries information?

Tags: open-source, api, knowledge-organization

I have a list of APIs I like and intend to use in my projects. Some of them I got from [this curated list of libraries](https://github.com/ziadoz/awesome-php/blob/master/README.md).

I'd like to organize it in an application that adds tags, categories and other information about libraries. 
Does know if anyone knows of an open-source application that can be used to organize and add metadata about libraries?

#### EDIT

As suggested by @Izzy, I'll list some requirements about the API I'm looking for:

- [Open source](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-source) / [gratis](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gratis)
- It can be developed for **Windows**/**Linux** or in **any programming language**. Preferably, in [php](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php), [python](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) or [Javascript](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript)
- It can have a GUI or it can be run in the CLI
- It would be better if it already has [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) features

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! What OS should that ap run on? And must it be [tag:gratis]/[tag:open-source], or how much would you spent on a paid solution? What features must it have apart from *storing* the information? What input formats must it support (I don't think you want to feed all details manually)? Does it need a GUI?

Comment: I edited my question with more requirements. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, getting clearer! Still open: how do you want to feed the data (manually, CSV Import, whatever)? And once they are in, what to do with them (query by criteria manually per GUI/TUI, access from other apps via some library, offering (fuzzy/RegEx/..) searches)?